# How to load Images in the list view according to Text name

Tags: android, arrays

I have a list view and BaseAdapter to Add one Image and One Text to row.My question is how can i load images in the list view according to text name.i know if i add images to Array according to text array i can get this done. but my text array load from service call.Every time text array order change then my image loading order is not correct..so can any one point me a way to get this done.Thank you

**BaseAdapter Class**

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> mtitle;

private int[] micon;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

Typeface tf;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, List<String> modules, int[] icon) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mtitle = modules;
    this.micon = icon;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mtitle.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

     Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf");

    title.setText(mtitle.get(position));
     title.setTypeface(type);
    icon.setImageResource(micon[position]);

    return itemView;

}

}
```

**images array**

```
private int[] photo;

photo = new int[]{R.drawable.btn_0011_home,R.drawable.btn_0010_accounts, R.drawable.btn_0009_contacts, R.drawable.btn_0008_opportunities,
                R.drawable.btn_0007_leads,R.drawable.btn_0006_calendar,R.drawable.btn_0005_documents,R.drawable.btn_0004_emails,R.drawable.btn_0003_campaigns, R.drawable.btn_0002_calls, R.drawable.btn_0001_meeting,
                R.drawable.btn_0000_tasks,  R.drawable.ic_launcher}

MenuListAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), moduleName, photo);
```

Comment: check  moduleName , photo both r equals

Comment: how can i check..i adding images as R.drawable.btn_001

Comment: try to add a logic to find the appropriate image for the title dynamically. is that possible?

Comment: send moduleName array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HashMap for this purpose. I assumed that the text and images count are equal. You put the text as a key and image name as value.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> imageData = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
imageData.put("Accounts", Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.btn_0010_accounts));
```

The constructor will be changed to:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> imageData;
public MenuListAdapter(Context context, List<String> modules, HashMap<String, Integer> imageData) {
this.context = context;
this.mtitle = modules;
this.imageData = imageData;

}
```

In the `getView()` method, you can the image as

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
  ........
  String textKey = mtitle.get(position);
  Integer imageResource = imageData.get(textKey);
  icon.setImageResource(imageResource.intValue());
  .........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you should do is upload the images to server with same name as it's in database so you can make the match based on these like `imageLoader.setImageresource(url+textview.getText.toString()+".png",imageview,options...);`

in your case try the following steps
1) change the drawable names similar to companynames in your database like R.drawable.companyname1 like that and keep a string array with these names with same positions like int array.String array={"R.drawable.companyname1",...etc};
2) inside getview method

```
 holder.text.setTag(position);
  holder.text.setText( tempValues.getCompanyName() );
     if(holder.text.getText().toString().equalsIgnorecase(array[Integer.parseInt(textview.GetTag().toString())){
     holder.image.setImageResource(                             array[Integer.parseInt(textview.GetTag().toString()));
    }
```

Comment: hey im very sorry 1st time i uploaded the question with wrong class.now i edited it.please check this.my bad.sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<Integer, ObjectPojo>` (ObjectPojo can contain whatever properties you need) instead of `List`. According to requirement you can modify the methods like `getItem, getCount, getView` etc.

For Image - `icon.setImageResource(map.get(integerId));`